# Select and Deselect UITableView Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, multipleselection, uitableviewrowaction

I have TableView with multiple rows, I am selecting them and adding them to the Label text when i deselect any of the row I am unable to remove it from Label Text

Here's My Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == categoryTable
        {
        let cell = self.categoryTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell") as! InquiryCategoryTableViewCell

        let Category:CategoryDB = categoryData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! CategoryDB
        print("Category = \(Category.category)")

            cell.categoryName.text = "\(Category.category)"
            cell.tintColor = color.UIColorFromRGB(0xCEEBFF)
            categoryTable.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
            categoryTable.setEditing(true, animated: false)



        return cell
        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if tableView == categoryTable
        {
            categoryList = categoryData[indexPath.row] as! CategoryDB

            self.category_id = categoryList!.catg_id



            print("Name = \(categoryList!.category)")
            print("ID = \(self.category_id)")
            categoryLabel.text! += "\(categoryList!.category), "
        }
}
```

Here's What i get as Output:

[image]

I first selected 3 rows it got appended to ***Label.text*** and after i deselect the row ***Label.text*** remains same

Anyone who can help me in this code?

Comment: you want to update the label when a row is deselected ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal Yup

Comment: so call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath just like you used didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @UmairAfzal let me try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a flag - hasSelected in CategoryDB

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if tableView == categoryTable
    {
        categoryList = categoryData[indexPath.row] as! CategoryDB

        categoryList!.hasSelected = true

        refreshLabel()
    }
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if tableView == categoryTable
    {
        categoryList = categoryData[indexPath.row] as! CategoryDB

        categoryList!.hasSelected = false

        refreshLabel()
    }
```

}

```
func refreshLabel(){
     var label = ""
     for object in categoryData as! CategoryDB {
        if(object.hasSelected){
            label += "\(categoryList!.category), "
        }
     }
     categoryLabel.text! = label
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this one and its perfectly working for me,

Consider this sample variables

```
let animals : [String] = ["Dog","Cat","Lion","Tiger","Cow","Buffalo","Horse"]
var sampleArray = [String]()
var samleLabel = UILabel()
```

add this functionality in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{ 
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.textLabel!.text = animals [indexPath.row]

    if sampleArray.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!)
    {
        sampleArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        print(sampleArray)
        samleLabel.text = test().componentsJoinedByString(",")
    }
    else
    {
        sampleArray.append((cell.textLabel?.text)!)
         print(sampleArray)
        samleLabel.text = test().componentsJoinedByString(",")
    }  
}

func test()-> NSArray
{
    print(sampleArray)
    return sampleArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use an array to do this. Declare NSMutableArray at the top

```
var arrSelectedTexts:NSMutableArray = [String]()
```

Now in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if(!arrSelectedTexts.containsObject(categoryList!.category))
            arrSelectedTexts.addObject(categoryList!.category)

        //Now update your label using the objects of the array

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if(arrSelectedTexts.containsObject(categoryList!.category))
           arrSelectedTexts.removeObject(categoryList!.category)

        //Now update your label using the objects of the array
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing remove `categoryTable.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and  add it to `viewDidload` because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` manyn time when your cell reuse so no need to set it that many time!

Now you should implement `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method also.

In that method you will get `indexPath.row` for the row that will be `deSelect` or `unselect`, from that `indexPath.row` you can get your object from your array that you need to remove from the string that you are displaying in the label.

So, in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` first convert `your label text to mutable array` then remove object from that array then convert that array to string again and show on label!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to implement a delegate method of `UITableView` like below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // update your label here
}
```